# Advanced search in a Rest Api using spring / querydsl

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, querydsl

I'm using Spring Data / QueryDSL with web support, using the annotation `@EnableSpringDataWebSupport`.
This works well, and automatically maps a GET query to a `Predicate`. I can search my DTP objects using a query such as:

```
http://localhost/search/dtp?name=foo
```

I now need to add more complex queries, such as AND or OR clauses.

I found this library which seems to achieve what I want: [spring-data-querydsl-value-operators](https://bitbucket.org/gt_tech/spring-data-querydsl-value-operators/src/master)

My understanding is that I need to add the following code to my Repository interface to leverage this library:

```
@Override
default void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QDtp root) {
    bindings.bind(root.name).all(ExpressionProviderFactory::getPredicate);
    bindings.bind(root.description).all(ExpressionProviderFactory::getPredicate);
    ...
}
```

However I didn't need to have a `customize()` method before, and now it seems I need to have these new bindings for all the fields and sub-fields of my object. This could lead to maintaining issues: if a new field is added but the developer forgets to add this binding, then the search on  that field won't work as with the other fields.

This wasn't the case previously.

How could I make it so that these bindings are generic and applied to all fields and subfields of my object ?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you may just use this library: https://github.com/turkraft/spring-filter

It will let you run search queries such as:

> */search?filter=* **average**(ratings) **>** 4.5 **and** brand.name **in** ('audi', 'land rover') **and** (year **>** 2018 **or** km **<** 50000) and color **:** 'white' **and** accidents **is empty**